# What is the range of pressures a space shuttle can withstand?

Tags: space-shuttle

Pressures, as on the external surface of the space shuttle. I want to design my own functioning space shuttle (on an extremely fundamental level with consideration of only the external structure, nowhere close to the real thing) and would like to run a wind tunnel test on it, and I wanted to know what pressures a space shuttle can withstand in order to design my own spacecraft to match and potentially exceed those values.

I appreciate any help that anybody can give me, even if it happens to be some advice, constructive criticism, or the answer to my question.

Comment: This might be a question for [space.se]

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan They don't allow DIY rocketry. Of course, the problem is solved if the reference to building a spacecraft is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The [Shuttle Crew Operations Manual](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/390651main_shuttle_crew_operations_manual.pdf) has basic information which might answer your question. Starting on page 799 (section 4.3) you'll find Airspeed Limitations.

During ascent the dynamic pressure limit is 819 psf. The limit is based on thermal protection constraints, rather than other structural concerns.

During entry, the dynamic pressure limit varies by velocity. The limit is based on stability (controllability) constraints.

[image: Entry qbar limits]

During a Return to Launch Site (RTLS) abort, the allowed limits were a bit higher:

[image: RTLS qbar limits]

Page 1002 has a graph showing typical Ascent dynamic pressure:

[image]

Comment: [Good bot, good bot](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/81371/timeline). Wouldn't have seen it otherwise :)